# Getting id in mongoose post update One hook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

This is my mongoose model:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from "mongoose";

export interface IUserModel extends Document {
    username: string;
  
    id: string;
}

const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String },

  _id: { type: String }
});


UserSchema.post('updateOne', (doc) => {
  console.log("doc._id",doc._id);
});


const UserModel = mongoose.model<IUserModel>("user", UserSchema);
export default  UserModel;
```

I need to access the unique _id in the post hook after I have called updateOne method to call some logic with that id.

However ***doc._id*** prints undefined as does ***doc.id***.

when I console.log ***this*** it prints to the console:

```
{ default: Model { user } }
```

But when I try to access ***this["default"]*** it again gives error.

I am calling update method like this :

```
await UserModel.updateOne({_id: id},userModel)
```

mongoose version : "^5.11.10"

@types/mongoose version : "^5.10.3"

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any sort of error?

Comment: No error of any kind !

Comment: Can you prepare a minimal reproduction?